# QEMU 2.8.0-r1 with vfio VGA passthrough on Gentoo 4.8.17-hardened-r2 hangs on Radeon RX 480 reset

Tags: gentoo, qemu, vga-passtrough

I have Gentoo 4.8.17-hardened-r2 compiled for AMD64 running on an AMD FX 8350 CPU with an Asus M5A99X EVO R2.0 motherboard, and I have a QEMU 2.8.0-r1 VM with vfio PCI passthrough to an Asus AMD Radeon RX 480 DUAL video card, using Windows 10 Anniversary Edition as guest OS.

Whenever my guest OS tries to do what I believe is a GPU disconnection, my entire VM hangs and keeps eating all the CPU cores I have assigned to it. This means I have to do many convoluted workarounds to install my display drivers, which happens rather often because Windows 10's rolling release model also happens to include the latest Radeon drivers. Recently I attempted to change my simulated motherboard from default to Q35 hoping to take advantage of the better PCIE support, and this resulted in a situation where I cannot work around this issue anymore and ended up forcefully having to at least find out why QEMU hangs when Windows 10 disconnects from my GPU.

Comment: I found a mailing list post that explains a problem similar to mine: https://www.redhat.com/archives/vfio-users/2015-September/msg00009.html . There is some mention about experiencing different results with OVMF instead of SeaBIOS. I'll try that.

Comment: No luck with configuring OVMF. I ripped an .rpm package as specified on http://www.tianocore.org/ovmf/ and plugged it into my VM startup command, but I can't get it to boot my Windows 10 installation CD. All I get is an UEFI shell, and I'm pretty sure my installation CD is compatible with UEFI.